# Accessing row items in DataGrid_LoadingRow eventhandler

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to assign different tooltips to DataGrid rows according to certain conditions.

```
private void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow row = e.Row;

        if (row["AssemblySummary"].ToString.Contains("Class"))
        {
            row.ToolTip = "Class definition...";
        }

    }
```

I am getting "Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow'." If i have a row why cannot i access its items? How to access cell[i]?

Edit made: I am verry sorry, I needed to access first cell in the given row like it is done now. I still have the same error. Thank you

Comment: You are already at the row; you do not need to index over it.  Are you attempting to check to see if there is a column called 'Class?'  If so, you can check the DataBoundItem object of the row for this, and possibly interegate the value if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and let us know if it works:

```
DataGridRow row = e.Row;
DataRowView rView = row.Item as DataRowView
if(rView != null && rView.Item["AssemblySummary"].ToString().Contains("Class"))
    row.ToolTip = "Class definition...";
```

If it doesn't, then it could be that the visual row has been loaded, but the data hasn't been bound yet.

Comment: This does not work for me. I am assuming the data hasn't been bound yet. How do I get the data then?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data of the row using the DataContext property.

Try this link http://techiethings.blogspot.com/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html

Comment: Thank you. I guess this wold work only with data binding set in XAML. But this DataGrid getting info (at different times) in code from two different sources like this DataGrid.ItemsSource = DataTable1.DefaultView or  DataGrid.ItemsSource = DataTable2.DefaultView. So I am trying to get a content of a DataGrid cell directly. Is it possible?